# how to get "out of process iframe" by Chrome DevTools Protocol(Playwright)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium, playwright

`Page.getFrameTree` interface can't get "out of process iframe".

```
    browser = playwright.chromium.connect_over_cdp("http://localhost:9222")

    default_context = browser.contexts[0]

    page = default_context.pages[0]

    client = page.context.new_cdp_session(page)

    frameTree = client.send("Page.getFrameTree")["frameTree"]
```

What should I do！！！！